# Keras GRU input shape

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I have built a custom generator that outputs X data with shape (100,2,2048) belonging to Y 16 (16) classes to be passed to a GRU model for video classification.

100 is the sequence length, 2 is for 2 simultaneous camera views, each with 2048 features, extracted earlier with a feature extractor.

I need to pass this to GRU model, but it throws an error (`Input 0 of layer "gru" incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Sull shape received: (None,100,2,2048)`) when I set the input shape in the input layer to (100,2,2048).

Using just one camera view and setting the it to (100,2048) works.

What input shape do I need to set to accommodate the two cameras?

Comment: What you are trying does not make any sense, GRUs are recurrent networks so they expect inputs like (samples, timesteps, features), you cannot feed them 4D data, you need to rethink the problem and layers you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRU/LSTM in Keras with input sequence of varying length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482946/gru-lstm-in-keras-with-input-sequence-of-varying-length)